# elasticsearch, find exact phrase in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, exact-match

I want to search exact phrase in a single field.. and this is my approach:

```
"query": {
  "match_phrase": {                                             
    "word": "developer"
  }
}
```

but the point is this query will find any document that have this keyword `developer` :

like `"word": "developer"` and  `"word": "php developer"`

how can I create a query, that when I search for `developer` just return `"word": "developer`"  doc,

and when I searched for `php developer` return `"word": "php developer"` doc

thanks

Comment: Would you be ok with a solution that ranks exact matches better than other matches? i.e. searching for "developer" would first return "developer" and only then "php developer", while searching for "php developer" would first return "php developer" and only then other "developer"

Comment: by the way, if you use `match_phrase` to find `php developer`, you should not get `developer` back.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple way, if your  field `word` would be of type `keyword`, you can then make use of [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) as shown below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "word" : "developer" } 
  }
}
```

If you have `word` as only of type `text` I'd suggest you to add its `keyword` field as [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), in that way you can make use of `word` for text matches and `word.keyword` for exact matches.

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "word": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type":  "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```